# Find a basis for $ker(\alpha)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

let $\alpha$: $\mathbb M_{3x3}(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ be defined by 
$$ \alpha: [a_{ij}]\to \sum_{i}^{3}\sum_{j}^{3}a_{i,j}$$
show that $\alpha$ is a linear transformation and find a basis for ker($\alpha$).
I am mostly not sure about the basis of ker($\alpha$).

Comment: Hint: Think a $3\times 3$ matrix as a vector of length $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint from @user251257, you may regard it as a map:
$$(a_1,...,a_9)\mapsto (a_1+...+a_9),$$
which is more easier to think about if it is a linear map (but you still have to check on the original map), and its kernel is just
$$\{(a_1,...,a_9)\in\Bbb{R}^9|a_1+...+a_9=0\}.$$
A way to simplify the process of finding the basis of the kernel is first to find its dimension. Since the map is obviously surjective, we can have the dimension of the kernel is $\dim_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{R}^9-\dim_\Bbb{R}\text{Im}\alpha=9-1=8.$ Then just find $8$ independent elements in the kernel and done!